# How can i store data from arduino sensor to hadoop hdfs in real time

Tags: python, hadoop, arduino, hdfs, bigdata

I am working on a project that involves using hdfs, and i want to store arduino data into hadoop hdfs every 3s in a csv file.

csv file example:

'temp1','datetime1','location1'

'temp2','datetime2','location2'

'temp3','datetime3','location3'

and every 3s i want to add a row to this csv file.

i've already tried a python code that read from arduino's serial port and write into a nosql database and i tried to do the same but i found some problems on hdfs path.

```py
# Creating a simple Pandas DataFrame
liste_temp = [temp_string,datetime.datetime.now(),temperature_location]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'temp' : liste_temp})
# Writing Dataframe to hdfs
with client_hdfs.write('/test/temp.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as writer:
                df.to_csv(writer)
```

Error:

```
File "templog.py", line 33, in <module> with client_hdfs.write('/test/temp.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as writer: File "C:\Users\nouhl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 460, in write raise
InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'hdfs://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/test/temp.csv
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @benWatson    File "templog.py", line 33, in <module>
    with client_hdfs.write('/test/temp.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as writer:
  File "C:\Users\nouhl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hdfs\client.py", line 460, in write

raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'hdfs://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/test/temp.csv'


i think its a connection problem between python and hdfs

Comment: In general, real-time sensor ingestion is handled from Kafka or Flume before writing to HDFS, not directly from the sensor devices